# C# Xamarin Forms - Executing task, with timeout

Tags: c#, xamarin, timeout, async-await

Like many others, I need to write a function that returns a task, and I want that task to automatically time out after a certain period.

The initial code looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> m_source;

    public Task<string> GetDataFromServer()
    {
        m_source = new TaskCompletionSource<string> ();

        // System call I have no visibility into, and that doesn't inherently take any
        // sort of timeout or cancellation token
        ask_server_for_data_and_when_youve_got_it_call(Callback);

        return m_source.Task;
    }

    protected void Callback(string data);
    {
        // Got the data!
        m_source.TrySetResult(data);
    }
}
```

Now I want this to be a little smarter, and time itself out when appropriate.  I have several options for doing this:

```
class MyClass
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> m_source;

    public Task<string> GetDataFromServer(int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        m_source = new TaskCompletionSource<string> ();

        ask_server_for_data_and_when_youve_got_it_call(Callback);

        // Method #1 to set up the timeout:
        CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken ();
        CancellationTokenSource cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource (ct);
        cts.CancelAfter (timeoutInSeconds * 1000);
        cts.Token.Register(() => m_source.TrySetCancelled());

        // Method #2 to set up the timeout:
        CancellationTokenSource ct2 = new CancellationTokenSource ();
        ct2.CancelAfter (timeoutInSeconds * 1000);
        ct2.Token.Register (() => m_source.TrySetCancelled());

        // Method #3 to set up the timeout:
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew (async () =>
        {
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay (timeoutInSeconds * 1000);
            m_source.TrySetCancelled();
        });

        // Method #4 to set up the timeout:
        Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer (new TimeSpan (0, 0, timeoutInSeconds),
            () => m_source.TrySetCancelled());

        return m_source.Task;
    }

    protected void Callback(string data);
    {
        // Got the data!
        m_source.TrySetResult(data);
    }
}
```

What are the plusses and minuses to the 4 different ways of setting up a timeout?  For instance, I'm guessing that method #2 is the most "lightweight" (requiring the fewest system resources)?

Are there other ways to set up a timeout that I've missed?

p.s.

One piece of knowledge I found out the hard way - if you call GetDataFromServer() from a thread besides the main UI thread:

```
Task.Run(() => await GetDataFromServer());
```

On iOS, the fourth method (Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer) never fires

Comment: The first function is async, so it should return the string, and not the Task. If you want this function to return the task itself, remove the `async` keyword

Comment: I've added the 'await' function that is why I have the 'async' keyword.

Comment: But this doesn't even compile... It looks like your are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. First you send a async request to the server, and then a synchronous request with a callback. A function with `public async Task<string>......` should return a string

Comment: You are right, this is not my actual code, but just sample code to help explain my question.  I've updated the code to remove the 'async'.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's easier to just use `Task.Delay` and `Task.WhenAny`:

```
public async Task<string> GetDataFromServerAsync(int timeoutInSeconds)
{
  Task<string> requestTask = GetDataFromServerAsync();
  var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeoutInSeconds);
  var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(requestTask, timeoutTask);
  if (completedTask == timeoutTask)
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
  return await requestTask;
}
```

Cons of the other approaches:

Method #1: Creates a new `CancellationToken` for no reason. It's just a less-efficient version of Method #2.

Method #2: Normally, you should be disposing the result of `Register` once the task completes. In this case, it would probably work OK since the CTS is always eventually cancelled.

Method #3: Uses `StartNew` just to call `Delay` - not sure of the reasoning there. It's essentially a less-efficient version of `Delay` with `WhenAny`.

Method #4: Would be acceptable. Though you do have to deal with `TaskCompletionSource<T>` and its quirks (e.g., synchronous continuations by default).

Comment: So now we have 5 methods to implement the timeout!  I'm still curious about the plusses and minuses of each method, why you might pick one over the other in some given situation ...

Comment: @BettyCrokker: Edited with opinions.

Comment: Why do you return "await requestTask" instead of just "requestTask"?

Comment: @BettyCrokker: That wouldn't compile.

Comment: Right.  Sorry, I'm relatively new to async/await, still getting used to the oddities of the syntax.